# Signing my solution with a digital certificate

Tags: visual-studio, clickonce, digital-certificate

I have an application developed with Visual Studio 2008 and distributed throught ClickOnce. This application is created especially for one client. The network administrator of this company allows me to install this application only with signed executable with a digital certificate. A policy rule will check for the signed certificate on my executable and block otherwise.

**My question**: do I need to have both setup.exe (ClickOnce) and mysoft.exe (the application installed by this ClickOnce package) signed with a digital certificate?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you would need to sign both files, but this is not a problem at all - just another line in the building script.

Note, that you would also need to timestamp the signature. Timestamp server address is specified as a parameter in signtool.exe call. The issuer of the code signing certificate (CA) should provide the address of its timestamping server, but not all CAs have timestamping servers. In any case you can use timestamping servers of large CAs such as Verisign, Comodo or GlobalSign.

Answer (score 1):

Good article how to configure VisualStudio to sign app before ClickOnce publishing: http://www.systenics.com/blog/sign-click-once-applications-with-godaddy-code-signing-certificate-and-visual-studio-2012-for-deployment-over-internet/

> Firstly, the setup.exe bootstrap file generated by Visual Studio needs to be signed, then the application and deployment manifests need to be signed and finally the application executable needs to be digitally signed.